# Going down to a deeper level in database to find stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString))
{
   conn.Open();

   using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
   {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.CommandText = "storedprocedure";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", param);
```

This connection string connects to the folder containing my databases, and I don't know how to access the stored procedure in one of those databases. How would I delve deeper to get my stored procedure?

Comment: Is that an actual folder containing MDB files, not a connection string to a Sql Server instance, for example ?

Comment: What exactly does your connection string look like?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the stored procedures? Just list them? You could run a query like `SELECT name FROM database_name.sys.procedures;`

Comment: You don't go into the MDF and LDF files: you submit a request to the database engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by folders, but if this is SQL Server 2008, you'd just reference the database/owner(schema?)/name

ex:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "MyDatabase.dbo.MyProcedure";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", param);
```

Comment: Definitely schema, not owner.

Comment: i thought so, but then i edited it to include 'owner' after i started questioning myself... by default i think it names the schema after the user if you don't specify one

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string to go to the database that you actually want to connect to.  You should use the connection string as intended instead of trying to figure out a work around for this.

Take a look at this site for information on how to configure connection strings:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008